# How to set dateformat for both Date and Calendar in Spring boot WebMvcConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using following custom config for WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to support lazy objects and also to support both XML and JSON response:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonJsonMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Registering Hibernate5Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;
    }

    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter jacksonXmlMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        // Registering Hibernate5Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        // Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        // To support XML
        converters.add(jacksonXmlMessageConverter());
        // To support JSON
        converters.add(jacksonJsonMessageConverter());
        // To support Resources (File Download)
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

I am able to get Calendar object (timestamp) as expected. i.e., yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
But I am unable to post Date object in format "yyyy-MM-dd".

How to add custom config to support both formats i.e., java.util.Date as "yyyy-MM-dd" and java.util.Calendar as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ?

Comment: Can you try the `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate` data types for your rest/api inputs? That is kinda the preferred since Java is trying to simplify/consolidate the date/time API.

Comment: @alltej can you please provide any sample ?

Comment: is this pure spring mvc or spring boot based?

Comment: Spring boot based